# Static count(Android)

Tags: java, android, count

In the method `bounce()` the value of count in first increment is not taken forward to second increment..I meant supose `count=0`..then first time i increment count its value becomes 1 nd second time also the vaue becomes 1..thats may be because both count are stored in different memory location...if i make count static then each time i run the application it retains the value stored in it last time which i don't want..i want the value of count in first increment should be  taken forward to second increment...also i can't put count outside if loop inside `bounce()` method as it will give the wroung output..what should i do?

```
public class Ball {

private Point p;               //Represents the x and y position of the Ball
private int c;                 //Represents the color of the Ball
private int r;                 //Represents the Radius of the Ball.
private int dx;                   //Represents the change in x position of the Ball. (Horizontal Speed)
private int dy;               //Represents the change in y position of the Ball. (Vertical Speed)
private Paint paint;           //Android Object holding the color for drawing on the canvas
public int count = 0;
public Ball(int x,int y,int col,int radius)
{

    p=new Point(x,y);
    c=col;
    r=radius;
    paint=new Paint();
    dx=0;
    dy=0;
}
public int getCount()
{return count;
}
public int getX()                       //Returns the x position of the ball as an integer
{return p.x;
}
public int getY()                      //Returns the y position of the ball as an integer
{
    return p.y;
}

public int getRadius()               //Returns the Radius of the ball as an integer
{return r;
}
public Paint getPaint()            //Returns the Paint of the Ball as a Paint Object
{return paint;
}
public void setColor(int col)      //Sets the Color of the Ball
{c=col;
if (paint == null) 
    paint = new Paint();
 paint.setColor(col);
}
public void goTo(int x,int y)       //Sets the x and y positions of the Ball
{p.x=x;
p.y=y;
}
public void setDX(int speed)      //Sets the Horizontal Speed of the Ball
{dx=speed;
}
public void setDY(int speed)       //Sets the Vertical Speed of the Ball
{
    dy=speed;
}
public void move()                 //Changes the x and y position by the dx and dy values
{
    p.x=p.x+dx;
    p.y=p.y+dy;
}
public void setX(int x)
{
    p.x = x;
}
public void setY(int y)
{
    p.y = y;
}
public int getDX()
{
    return p.x;
}
public int getDY()
{
    return p.y;
}
public void bounce(Canvas canvas)       //Bounces off the Sides of the Canvas
{ 
    move();
    if(p.x>canvas.getWidth()|| p.x<0)
    {
        count++;
        dx=dx * -1;
    }
    if(p.y>canvas.getWidth()|| p.y<0)
    {
        count++;
        dy=dy * -1;
    }


    MainActivity.tv.setText(String.valueOf(getCount()));
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show how you are implementing your class. If you create a new instance of the `Ball` class each time you use it, then you will set your `count = 0` every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I should add my comments as an answer. You should only create one instance of the `Ball` class and use it. Each time you create a new instance of `Ball`, you set `count = 0`

Comment: i declare count as static and initialized it to 0 inside its constructor

Comment: @user3503165: No, *don't* make it static - it's perfectly fine to be an instance variable, just avoid creating multiple instances of `Ball`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use singleton class to maintain your count increment ,and whenever application starts make it zero . instead of static making Singleton class and maintain count in that class using setter and getter  method is beat easy .

Comment: There should be absolutely *no* need to use a singleton here. Lunchbox's comment on the question is spot on - there must be multiple instances of `Ball` being created here.